# Eclipse CDT does not index code between #if SYMBOL #endif

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I am working in webkit with Eclipse CDT as IDE, there are some classes under #if ENABLE(VIDEO) but eclipse does not index it. It thinks that they are unused blocks, is there any way by which I can tell eclipse to index everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about the solution you suggested, but there's another:

Open your project's properties, go to `C/C++ General` -> `Path and Symbols` -> `Symbols`, make sure you have `Configuration` set to `All configurations` and then add there any preprocessor symbols you'd like to have defined.

Answer (score 1):

Please check

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=240194#c1

If you for example have problems in indexing "#if DEBUG" then the indexing result will depend on how DEBUG is defined.

> This really depends on the definition of the DEBUG macro:
>
> #define DEBUG    ---> // syntax error (#if with no expression)
>
> #define DEBUG 1  ---> // ok, selects if-branch (#if 1)
>
> #define DEBUG 0  ---> // ok, selects else-branch (#if 0)
>
> #undef DEBUG     --->  // ok, selects else-branch (#if DEBUG)
>
> You should probably use #ifdef DEBUG instead.

Or you can define DEBUG = 1.

Go to Project --> Settings --> C/C++ General --> Preprocessor Include --> Entries.

Under "Setting Entries" select "CDT User Setting Entries".

Then "Add..."

Then select "Preprocessor Macro" and add the name and value.